# VTK Examples not working - QVTKOpenGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I tried getting into Qt and VTK and i had a lot of obstacles to get this far. google and stackoverflow helped me quite a lot but i can't solve this problem by myself. It is about the QVTKOpenGLWidget. I don't know how to get this and this example isn't working for me:

https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Qt/RenderWindowUISingleInheritance/

I also had to add the following line to the CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(VTK_DIR "/path/to/cmake/vtk-8.0" CACHE PATH "VTK directory override" FORCE)
```

If i try to run it i get the following errormessages:

RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.cxx:21:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘QVTKOpenGLWidget::SetRenderWindow(vtkNew&)’
   this->ui->qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.cxx:34:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘vtkRenderer::AddActor(vtkNew&)’
   renderer->AddActor(sphereActor);

RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.cxx:37:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘vtkRenderWindow::AddRenderer(vtkNew&)’
   this->ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer);

I don't know where this QVTKOpenGLWidget is coming from and how i get it but it seems like you have to use this instead of QVTKOpenWidget with Qt5 but it seems like it's not working? I don't have much experience with Qt or VTK in general. So it might be easy to solve.

RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.cxx:

```
#include "RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.h"
// This is included here because it is forward declared in
// RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.h
#include "ui_RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.h"

#include <vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkNew.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>

// Constructor
RenderWindowUISingleInheritance::RenderWindowUISingleInheritance()
{
  this->ui = new Ui_RenderWindowUISingleInheritance;
  this->ui->setupUi(this); //*1

  vtkNew<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow> renderWindow;
  this->ui->qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow); //*2


  // Sphere
  vtkNew<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource;
  sphereSource->Update();
  vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> sphereMapper;
  sphereMapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());
  vtkNew<vtkActor> sphereActor;
  sphereActor->SetMapper(sphereMapper); //*3

  // VTK Renderer
  vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;
  renderer->AddActor(sphereActor); //*4

  // VTK/Qt wedded
  this->ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer); //*5

  // Set up action signals and slots
  connect(this->ui->actionExit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(slotExit())); //*6

}

void RenderWindowUISingleInheritance::slotExit()
{
  qApp->exit(); //*7
}
```

It is also telling me the following things (marked the lines in the code with //*X):

1. Class 'Ui_RenderWindowUISingleInheritance' doesn't have a function 'setupUI'
2. Class 'Ui_RenderWindowUISingleInheritance' doesn't have a field 'qvtkWidget'
3. Parameter type mismatch: Types 'vtkMapper*' and 'vtkNew' are not compatible
4. Parameter type mismatch: Types 'vtkProp*' and 'vtkNew' are not compatible
5. Class 'Ui_RenderWindowUISingleInheritance' doesn't have a field 'qvtkWidget'
6. Class 'Ui_RenderWindowUISingleInheritance' doesn't have a field 'actionExit'
7. Can't resolve variable 'qApp'

I hope someone can help me since i want to get into VTK and Qt and this seems to be one of the last challenges before i can start working with them. Even if you can only help with a small part of this please let me know since every small step might help me to solve the rest by myself!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have similar issues. Setup with these two is very painful. I read that QVTKWidget is in process of being deprecated, so all the examples use QVTKOpenGlWidget. But there is almost no documentation about how to make them work together

Comment: The Example build and works flawlessly with VTK master. You may want to update your version of VTK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build this example in my enviroment. To compile you will need correct the file **RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.cxx** putting **.get()** in these objects SetRenderWindow(**renderWindow.Get()**), SetMapper(**sphereMapper.Get()**), AddActor(**sphereActor.Get()**) and AddRenderer(**renderer.Get()**):

```
#include "RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.h"

// This is included here because it is forward declared in
// RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.h
#include "ui_RenderWindowUISingleInheritance.h"

#include <vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkNew.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>

// Constructor
RenderWindowUISingleInheritance::RenderWindowUISingleInheritance()
{
  this->ui = new Ui_RenderWindowUISingleInheritance;
  this->ui->setupUi(this);

  vtkNew<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow> renderWindow;
  this->ui->qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow.Get());


  // Sphere
  vtkNew<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource;
  sphereSource->Update();
  vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> sphereMapper;
  sphereMapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());
  vtkNew<vtkActor> sphereActor;
  sphereActor->SetMapper(sphereMapper.Get());

  // VTK Renderer
  vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;
  renderer->AddActor(sphereActor.Get());

  // VTK/Qt wedded
  this->ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer.Get());

  // Set up action signals and slots
  connect(this->ui->actionExit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(slotExit()));

}

void RenderWindowUISingleInheritance::slotExit()
{
  qApp->exit();
}
```